# How can I change json using exec()?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a problem. An existing project requires a json change, before that I used jmespath and everything was fine, but now I need to add to json, I tried to do it like this:

```
str = "d[\'start\']" + path[5:len(path)-4].replace("child", "[\'child\']").replace("[*]", "").replace(".", "")
        str=str[:len(str)-9]+".append(child:[{'cmd': get_result_from_db(id), 'message': result}])"
        print(str)
        exec(str)
        json.dump(d, f,indent=4)
```

I opened json earlier like this:

```
with open('info1.json', encoding="cp1251") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
```

I understand that the first piece of code looks wild, but it doesn't throw exceptions until `exec(str)`
I checked, my path is parsed correctly, and here is the exception itself:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

And I understand that append is not applicable to lists, but how can I upload changes to json?

P.S
I will give an example of the structure of a json file

```
    {
  "start": [
    {
      "cmd": "1",
      "message": "main",
      "child": [
        {
          "cmd": "1",
          "message": "something."
        },
        {
          "cmd": "3",
          "message": "this"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add a `child:[{'cmd': get_result_from_db(id), 'message': result}]` to the place where `"message": "this"`.
How can I do this with a json path to the desired location?

Comment: As a side note, `path[5:len(path)-4]` can be written as `path[5:-4]`. A negative endpoint is assumed to be backwards from the end.

Comment: @tdelaney ,hmm, thanks, I'll take that into account

Comment: We really can't guess what your input JSON looks like; could you please [edit] your question to include example input and expected output?

Comment: Why do you use `encoding="cp1251"`? JSON by definition is UTF-8.

Comment: Performing lexical replacement smack dab in the middle of a JSON stream seems extremely brittle. Read it into a `dict`, modify it, and dump it back to JSON.

Comment: @tripleee ,I use encoding cp1251, because in my json file Russian letters, as I already wrote the path is parsed correctly. the problem is that now "d [\'start\'] " + path[5:len(path)-4]. replace ("child", "[\'child\']"). replace("[*]", "").replace(".", "")
str=str[:len(str)-9] counts as a list, not as json

Comment: This is tangential, but Unicode can accommodate Cyrillic just fine; the file is not really valid JSON if it uses some legacy 8-bit encoding.

Comment: @tripleee ,it's not about json, it is processed correctly, but exec does not return anything

Comment: Again, **please** [edit] to show example input and expected output. Using `exec` for this is completely crazy, but we can't show you how to do it properly when the requirements are entirely unclear.

Comment: So the expected output should be `{ "start": [ { "cmd": "1", "message": "main",  "child": [ { "cmd": "1", "message": "something." }, { "cmd": "3", "message": "this" }, { "cmd": XX, "message": YY } ] } ] }`, where XX and YY are calculated by Python at runtime, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to inject values at fixed offsets within a string whose length you can't reliably predict, just read the JSON into a dictionary and manipulate that.

```py
d['start'][0]['child'].append({
    'cmd': get_result_from_db(id),
    'message': result})
json.dump(d, f, indent=4)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/2ktkVW

Comment: `id` is not a good identifier name but of course it happens to work (-:

Comment: Maybe also notice that order in JSON dictionaries is not something you can easily control; the demo link currently displays `message` before `cmd` in all the entries, but that could change at any time.